# How do I define custom endpoint paths in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

Inside a micronaut microservice, I would like to change the prometheus metrics route which is generated by micrometer to a custom path. The default one is /admin/prometheus. Is there any way to change the default path of endpoints, for example for metrics or prometheus, inside the application.yml without adding another controller?

I tried to define a 'path' inside application.yml, but this did not work out.

Comment: Post some code with more details please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to change it only by configuration because endpoint path is statically defined by the `@Endpoint` annotation, see:

```java
    @Endpoint(PrometheusEndpoint.ID)
    public class PrometheusEndpoint {

        public static final String ID = "prometheus";
        ...
    }
```

[Full source code of PrometheusEndpoint.](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-registry-prometheus/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/metrics/micrometer/prometheus/management/PrometheusEndpoint.java)

There is a strategy to solve as much as possible during compile time in Micronaut and this is why it is so fast and with low memory consumption.

I'm afraid that if you really need to change path of any Micronaut existing endpoint you should fork it and change it in the existing code or better create own endpoint and expose original functionality through it.